# simple html photo album

Tags: html

i don't know anything about HTML  coding and i want create a photo album like this website :[link text](http://www.gem1.tv)

but without fade in and out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these image galleries:

[One](http://www.valums.com/javascript-image-galleries/)

[Two](http://www.dejurka.ru/css/gallery/)

[Three](http://tutorialblog.org/12-javascript-image-galleries/)

But you must know basics of html, css and JavaScript. Begin from learning basics!

Answer (score 2):

Then you should learn HTML, CSS, Javascript, and probably a server-side programming language.

StackOverflow is not a programming course.

Alternatively, you could use a pre-packaged photo album template, such as [one of these](http://www.paulvanroekel.nl/picasa/).

Answer (score -1):

you should learn first
a> tag for linking
&
img> tag for image.

Dreamveaver help you design a better web page.

BUT STUDY AND TRY